# How to pass Array[Seq[String]] to apache spark udf? (Error: Not Applicable)

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following apache spark udf in scala:

```
val myFunc = udf {
  (userBias: Float, otherBiases: Map[Long, Float],
    userFactors: Seq[Float], context: Seq[String]) => 
    var result = Float.NaN

    if (userFactors != null) {
      var contexBias = 0f

      for (cc <- context) {
       contexBias += otherBiases(contextMapping(cc))
      }

      // definition of result
      // ...
    }
    result
}
```

Now I want to pass parameters to this function, however I always get the message Not Applicable due to the parameter `context`. I know that user defined functions take inputs by rows, and this function runs if I delete `context`... How to solve this issue? Why doesn't it read rows from `Array[Seq[String]]`, i.e. from `context`? Alternatively, it would be acceptable to pass`context` as `DataFrame` or something similar.

```
// context is Array[Seq[String]]
val a = sc.parallelize(Seq((1,2),(3,4))).toDF("a", "b")
val context = a.collect.map(_.toSeq.map(_.toString))

// userBias("bias"), otherBias("biases") and userFactors("features")
// have a type Column, while userBias... are DataFrames
myDataframe.select(dataset("*"),
                   myFunc(userBias("bias"),
                          otherBias("biases"),
                          userFactors("features"),
                          context)
                   .as($(newCol)))
```

**UPDATE:**

I tried the solution indicated in the answer of `zero323`, however still there is a small issue with `context: Array[Seq[String]]`. In particular the problem is with looping over this Array `for (cc <- context) { contexBias += otherBiases(contextMapping(cc)) }`. I should pass a String to `contextMapping`, not a `Seq[String]`:

```
  def myFunc(context: Array[Seq[String]]) = udf {
    (userBias: Float, otherBiases: Map[Long, Float],
     userFactors: Seq[Float]) =>
      var result = Float.NaN

      if (userFactors != null) {
        var contexBias = 0f
        for (cc <- context) {
          contexBias += otherBiases(contextMapping(cc))
        }

        // estimation of result

      }
      result
  }
```

Now I call it as follows:

```
myDataframe.select(dataset("*"),
                   myFunc(context)(userBias("bias"),
                                   otherBias("biases"),
                                   userFactors("features"))
           .as($(newCol)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Spark 2.2+**

You can use `typedLit` functions:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.typedLit

myFunc(..., typedLit(context))
```

**Spark < 2.2**

Any argument that is passed directly to the UDF has to be a `Column` so if you want to pass constant array you'll have to convert it to column literal:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{array, lit}

val myFunc: org.apache.spark.sql.UserDefinedFunction = ???

myFunc(
  userBias("bias"),
  otherBias("biases"),
  userFactors("features"),
  // org.apache.spark.sql.Column
  array(context.map(xs => array(xs.map(lit _): _*)): _*)  
)
```

Non-`Column` objects can be passed only indirectly using closure, for example like this:

```
def myFunc(context: Array[Seq[String]]) = udf {
  (userBias: Float, otherBiases: Map[Long, Float],  userFactors: Seq[Float]) => 
    ???
}

myFunc(context)(userBias("bias"), otherBias("biases"), userFactors("features"))
```

Comment: Note that Spark 2.2 has not been released yet.

Answer (score 0):

The alternative way is to use struct

```
val seq: Seq[String] = ...
val func: UserDefinedFunction = udf((seq: Row) => ...)
val seqStruct = struct(seq.map(v => lit(v)): _*)
func(seqStruct)
```