# Pass Array[seq[String]] to UDF in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I am new to UDF in spark. I have also read the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37330966/how-to-pass-arrayseqstring-to-apache-spark-udf-error-not-applicable)

Problem statement: I'm trying to find pattern matching from a dataframe col.

Ex: Dataframe

```
val df = Seq((1, Some("z")), (2, Some("abs,abc,dfg")),
             (3,Some("a,b,c,d,e,f,abs,abc,dfg"))).toDF("id", "text")

df.show()

+---+--------------------+
| id|                text|
+---+--------------------+
|  1|                   z|
|  2|         abs,abc,dfg|
|  3|a,b,c,d,e,f,abs,a...|
+---+--------------------+


df.filter($"text".contains("abs,abc,dfg")).count()
//returns 2 as abs exits in 2nd row and 3rd row
```

Now I want to do this pattern matching for every row in column $text and add new column called count.

Result:

```
+---+--------------------+-----+
| id|                text|count|
+---+--------------------+-----+
|  1|                   z|    1|
|  2|         abs,abc,dfg|    2|
|  3|a,b,c,d,e,f,abs,a...|    1|
+---+--------------------+-----+
```

I tried to define a udf passing $text column as Array[Seq[String]. But I am not able to get what I intended.

What I tried so far:

```
val txt = df.select("text").collect.map(_.toSeq.map(_.toString)) //convert column to Array[Seq[String]
val valsum = udf((txt:Array[Seq[String],pattern:String)=> {txt.count(_ == pattern) } )
df.withColumn("newCol", valsum( lit(txt) ,df(text)) )).show()
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: how are you deciding the value of `count`? why is it equal to `2` for the second row?

Comment: @philantrovert if pattern `z` exists in the any other column , then is counted as 1. In above example `abs,abc,dfg` is one whole string, which also present partially in 3 row `a,b,c,d,e,f,abs,abc,dfg`, thats why its 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to know all the elements of `text` column which can be done using `collect_list` by `grouping` all the `rows` of your `dataframe` as one. Then just check if element in `text` column in the collected array and `count` them as in the following code.

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._

val df = Seq((1, Some("z")), (2, Some("abs,abc,dfg")),(3,Some("a,b,c,d,e,f,abs,abc,dfg"))).toDF("id", "text")

val valsum = udf((txt: String, array : mutable.WrappedArray[String])=> array.filter(element => element.contains(txt)).size)
df.withColumn("grouping", lit("g"))
  .withColumn("array", collect_list("text").over(Window.partitionBy("grouping")))
  .withColumn("count", valsum($"text", $"array"))
  .drop("grouping", "array")
  .show(false)
```

You should have following output

```
+---+-----------------------+-----+
|id |text                   |count|
+---+-----------------------+-----+
|1  |z                      |1    |
|2  |abs,abc,dfg            |2    |
|3  |a,b,c,d,e,f,abs,abc,dfg|1    |
+---+-----------------------+-----+
```

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: thx for you answer. What I am trying to do is to find `z` in $text coloumn and it appears ones, similarly , I am looking for pattern `abs,abc,dfg` in whole $text col and its appears twice (2 row,3 row)

Comment: is your final result in dataframe or just counts?

Comment: the final result should be a Dataframe with a newCol of counts(pattern matched)

Comment: can you explain how you get your final dataframe? how did you get 1 for first row, 2 for second row and 1 for the third row?

Comment: if i call the UDF with like `df.withColumn("newCol", valsum( lit(txt) ,df(text)) )).show()`. The first argument is the `Array[Seq[String]]` and second arg is a Datframe col. For every row of this col, does the pattern matching. Ex: `z` in the `Array[Seq[String]]` and should return 1 because array has just one z , but for second pattern `abs,abc,dfg`, it is present is 2nd and 3rd row, hence count 2. This is what I want to achieve

Comment: how come your third row has 1 then? doesn't it need to be 2 as well?

Comment: because the string`a,b,c,d,e,f,abs,abc,dfg` apeas just once in the whole col.

Comment: thanks for the solution it works. I also meanwhile came up with a solution. I will post soon